# Redis Server Failure when server starts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redis

When I start redis on OSX, it exits because it says it can't handle RDB format version 7. Here's the output:

```
Server started, Redis version 3.0.7
Can't handle RDB format version 7
Fatal error loading the DB: Invalid argument. Exiting.
```

The redis gem version in the gemfile was 3.2.2, but I changed it to 3.0.7 to see if that would make it work. It didn't.

How do I fix this? I don't have anything important in there so I'm fine with resetting it to another version or uninstall and reinstall redis.

Comment: Simply delete the dump.rdb file - it is incompatible with the version that you're running

Comment: where to find this file?

Comment: @ArunGowda It is here on Win10 - C:\Program Files\Redis

Comment: @ArunGowda In Linux, type "CONFIG get dir" in redis-cli prompt to get location detail. Default location will be "/var/lib/redis"

Answer (score 12):

I SOLVED the problem by deleting the **/home/marco/dump.rdb** file from redis folder.

Comment: I too deleted my dump.rdb file from Redis folder and it worked for me.

Comment: A location for dump.rdb could be found in /etc/redis/redis.conf, search for "dir", a working directory. For me it was /var/lib/redis/ on Ubuntu and deleting dump.rdb got me over this error.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Itamar. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling via Homebrew. That was easiest solution for me since I didn't have any important info in the db.

```
 brew uninstall redis
 brew install redis
```

3.0.x is incompatible with 3.2.x so upgrading to 3.2.4 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue happened to me on **6.2.4** & I solved using this process

1. Search the Dump.rdb file

   `sudo find / -name *.rdb`

> For Ubuntu20 You'll find it under `/var/lib/redis/dump.rdb`

2. Delete the file dump.rdb

   `sudo rm /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb`
3. Restart Redis & Check the Status

   `sudo systemctl restart redis-server`

   `systemctl status redis-server.service`

Answer (score 1):

I had this in docker upon changing redis versions. Had to completely stop the container and remove volumes and restart it.

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.6-alpine
```

```bash
docker-compose down -v redis
docker-compose up redis
```

Comment: `docker-compose down` fixed it for me